# How to capture custom parameters in firebase deep link in Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, deep-linking

everyone!

I'm working for the first time ever  in a Unity game project using Firebase.

We configure our deep link in Firebase console to open our game in a specific mode when te deep link was sent.

That part works well. But we have a big issue:

We need to get a value form a custom parameter in the URL, because our server generates a random username for our game to make a Leader Board sandbox everytime the deep link was sent.

So we configure our deep link in Firebase console like this:

```
https://exemple.page.link/gamemode?username=123
```

But, in this case, the `username` will always be `123`. However, the server will always send the link with a random user, for example:

```
https://exemple.page.link/gamemode?username=8b9d-1c6b-c52a3-b0d7
```

If we leave the username parameter blank, even if the server sent the random username, we receive nothing in our link in Unity, just:

```
https://exemple.page.link/gamemode?username
```

If I manage to get the link in a browser in my Android device, I get the random username properly. But when the game opens, this value was lost!

To receive the dynamic link, we just use the `void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args)` in our Firebase Manager script in Unity.

So, my question is:

There is a way to receive the `username` parameter with a dynamic value? If the answer is 'yes', there's a method to get that custom value? Or I just missed up something in the firebase configuration or even the deep link in Firebase console?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [Receive Dynamic Links with Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity/receive) you need to cast to [`ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/dynamic-links/received-dynamic-link-event-args)

```cs
void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
    Debug.Log($"Received dynamic link {dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString}");
}
```

and then if there is only this one parameter anyway you could probably simply do e.g.

```cs
var query = dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.Query;
var username = query.Split('=')[1];
```

or if there can be more parameter

```cs
var query = dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.Query;
// first Split into the individual patamters
var patamters = query.Split('&');
string username = null;
foreach(var parameter in parameters)
{
    // Then split into key and value
    var keyValue = parameter.Split('=');

    if(keyValue[0] == "username")
    {
        username = keyValue[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

or if you happen to be a fan of Linq (not sure if this is the most elegant though)

```cs
var query = dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.Query;
var username = query.Split('&').Select(parameter => parameter.Split('=').Where(keyValue => keyValue[0] == "username").Select(keyValue => keyValue[1]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You're very clear in your response, @derHugo! Thank you so much!
However, when i used: 

`var query = dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.Query;`

I get this in query var:

`username=`

i.e. parameter is blank.


Did I forget something in the Firebase deep link configuration, perhaps?